# Submit form within bootstrap modal using ajax and codeigniter without page change

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I am trying to submit a form within a bootstrap modal using ajax. And my form is successfully submitted, but the success statements within ajax are not executed. The page is redirected to a blank page saying {"msg":"ok"}.
I am pasting the code from controller and view. Please help.

Controller

```
$update_profile_details = $this->userp_m->edit_profile_m($uname,$uemail,$data1,$new_email);

            if($update_profile_details == true)
            {
                $status['msg'] = 'ok';
            }
            else
            {
                $status['msg'] = 'err';
            }

            echo json_encode ($status);
```

View

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{   

$("#myForm").submit(function(e) 
{   
    e.preventDefault();
    var reg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    var name = $('#inputName').val();
    var email = $('#inputEmail').val();

    if (name.trim() == '') {
        alert('Please enter your name.');
        $('#inputName').focus();
        return false;
    } else if (email.trim() == '') {
        alert('Please enter your email.');
        $('#inputEmail').focus();
        return false;
    } else if (email.trim() != '' && !reg.test(email)) {
        alert('Please enter valid email.');
        $('#inputEmail').focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        var fd = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $('#myForm').attr('action'),
            dataType: "json",
            data: $('#myform').serialize(), fd,
            contentType: false,  
            cache: false,   
            processData:false,
            beforeSend: function() 
            {
                $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
            },
            success: function(status) 
            {
                alert(status);

                if (status.msg == 'ok') {
                    $('#inputName').val('');
                    $('#inputEmail').val('');
                    $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:green;">Changes have been saved successfully.</p>');
                } else 
                {
                    $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
                }

                $('.submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
            },
            error: function(status) 
            {
                alert("Some error, please try again");

            }
        });
    }

});
```

HTML

```
 <form id="myform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo site_url('User/user_index_c/edit_profile_c'); ?>">
    <label>Full Name : </label>
    <input class="name_styling" type="text" placeholder="Enter name" id="inputName" name="uname">

    <label>Email Id : </label>
    <input class="email_styling" type="email"  placeholder="Enter email" id="inputEmail" name="new_email">

    <div class="controls">
    <label>Profile Photo : </label>
    <input name="file1" type="file"  id="image_file" />
    <img id="blah" class="logoupload" src="#" alt="your image" />
    <span class="filename"></span>
    </div>

    <center><input class="submitBtn" id="submit" type="submit" value="Save Changes" name="submit" ></center>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of function you have to write jquery code like below.

**Remove** `function submitContactForm(e){}`

**Add** `$(document).on('submit', '#myform', function(e) { })`

```
$(document).on('submit', '#myform', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var reg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    var name = $('#inputName').val();
    var email = $('#inputEmail').val();
    if (name.trim() == '') {
        alert('Please enter your name.');
        $('#inputName').focus();
        return false;
    } else if (email.trim() == '') {
        alert('Please enter your email.');
        $('#inputEmail').focus();
        return false;
    } else if (email.trim() != '' && !reg.test(email)) {
        alert('Please enter valid email.');
        $('#inputEmail').focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        $('.submitBtn').prop("disabled", true);
        $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
        var myFormData = new FormData();
        e.preventDefault();
        var inputs = $('#myForm input[type="file"]');
        $.each(inputs, function(obj, v) {
            var file = v.files[0];
            var filename = $(v).attr("data-filename");
            var name = $(v).attr("name");
            myFormData.append(name, file, filename);
        });
        var inputs = $('#myForm input[type="text"],input[type="email"]');
        $.each(inputs, function(obj, v) {
            var name = $(v).attr("name");
            var value = $(v).val();
            myFormData.append(name, value);
        });
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open('POST', '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/User/user_index_c/edit_profile_c/', true);
        xhr.send(myFormData);
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    $('#inputName').val('');
                    $('#inputEmail').val('');
                    $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:green;">Changes have been saved successfully.</p>');
                    $('.submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
                    $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
                }
            }
        };
    }
});
```

Let me know if it not works.

Comment: The image upload stops, if I use the above

Comment: No error in console, the error function of ajax is executed

Comment: hey after the alert the page keeps loading and then again {"msg":"ok"} is displayed on new page. Is it because e.preventDefault() is not written?

Comment: Yes, If you use `e.PreventDefault()` then jquery will invalidate all default methods.

Comment: Without e.preventDefault() , the code didnt work. Is anything wrong with html?

Comment: Please share your current code in question so I can guide you.

Answer (score 0):

try this: in your file.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').click(function () {
         var name= $("#inputName").val();
         var mail = $("#inputEmail").val();
         var img = $("#image_file").val();
         $.post("User/user_index_c/edit_profile_c", {send_name:name,send_mail:mail, send_igm:img},
         function (data) {
             if (data.trim() != "ok") {
                alert('error');
              }
              else{
                  //action for "success" exemple: alert("send with success!"); and insert a code for clean fields
              }
          });
      });
  });
```

in your controller's method:

```
$uname = $this->input->post("send_name");
$uemail = $this->input->post("send_mail");
$new_email = $this->input->post("send_igm");

$update_profile_details =    $this->userp_m->edit_profile_m($uname,$uemail,$data1,$new_email);

if($update_profile_details == true){
    echo 'ok';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'err';
        }
```

I hope I have helped