# I am not getting any text value in form input in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, image, codeigniter

I am very new to Codeigniter. I m trying to create a form with some text input field along with two image upload field. The image uploading working fine but the text input field value are not coming. Can anyone please check my code and tell me where I am doing wrong  Here is my Code:

Front End

```
    <body>
        <div class="custom-container">
        <div id="msg"></div>
            <form  id="product-upload" action="/index.php/uploadproduct/upload" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8"  enctype="multipart/form-data"">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="product-name">Product name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_name" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="product-name">Product Code</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_code" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="product-name">Product Link</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_link" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="product-image">Product image</label>
                    <input type="file" id="product-image" name="product_image" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="product-name">Product Screenshots</label>
                    <input type="file" id="product-screen" name="product_screen" class="form-control" multiple>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="add-product" type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add new product">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#add-product').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var formData = new FormData();

                //for product profile images
                var productProfile = $('#product-image').prop('files')[0];
                formData.append('file',productProfile);

                // for product detail image
                var imageCount = document.getElementById('product-screen').files.length;
                for (var i = 0; i< imageCount; i++) {
                    formData.append("files[]", document.getElementById('product-screen').files[i]);
                }


                //AJAX Call
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost/ci/index.php/uploadproduct/upload/', // point to server-side controller method
                    dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the server
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: formData,
                    type: 'post',
                     beforeSend: function() {
                        // setting a timeout
                         $('#msg').html('Loading');
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#msg').html(response); // display success response from the server
                        $('input').attr('value').html();
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        $('#msg').html("no response"); // display error response from the server
                    }
                });
            });
        });

     </script>
```

Controller Script is this

```
       public function upload(){
            $uploadData = "";
            //Get the details 
            $productName = $_POST['product_name'];
            $productCode = $this->input->post('product_code');
            $productLink = $this->input->post('product_link');
            $uploadData = $productName.','.$productCode.','.$productLink;

            // setting cofig for image upload
            $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/profile/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
            $config['max_filename'] = '255';
            $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
            //$config['max_size'] = '1024'; //1 MB

            // Get the profile image
            $errorMsg = "";
            if (isset($_FILES['file']['name'])) {
                if (0 < $_FILES['file']['error']) {
                    $errorMsg = 'Error during file upload' . $_FILES['file']['error'];
                } else {
                    if (file_exists('uploads/profile/' . $_FILES['file']['name'])) {
                        $errorMsg =  'File already exists : uploads/profile/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
                    } else {
                        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('file')) {
                            $errorMsg =  $this->upload->display_errors();
                        } else {
                             $data = $this->upload->data();

                           $errorMsg =  'File successfully uploaded : uploads/profile/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
                           $uploadData = $uploadData.','.$data['full_path'];
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $errorMsg =  'Please choose a file';
            }


            //upload product screenshots
            $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
            if (isset($_FILES['files']) && !empty($_FILES['files'])) {
                $no_files = count($_FILES["files"]['name']);
                $link="";
                for ($i = 0; $i < $no_files; $i++) {
                    if ($_FILES["files"]["error"][$i] > 0) {
                        $errorMsg =  "Error: " . $_FILES["files"]["error"][$i] . "<br>";
                    } else {
                        if (file_exists('uploads/' . $_FILES["files"]["name"][$i])) {
                            $errorMsg =  'File already exists : uploads/' . $_FILES["files"]["name"][$i];
                        } else {
                            $fileOriginalNmame = $_FILES["files"]["name"][$i];
                            $explodeFile = explode(".",$fileOriginalNmame);
                            $fileExtenstion = end($explodeFile);
                            $fileName = md5(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)).$_FILES["files"]["name"][$i]).'.'.$fileExtenstion;
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$i], 'uploads/' . $fileName);

                            $link= $link.$fileName.',';



                        }
                    }

                }
                $uploadData =$uploadData .','.  $link;
                $errorMsg = $uploadData;
            } else {
                $errorMsg =  'Please choose at least one file';
            }

            echo $errorMsg;

        }
```

And if anyone can improve my controller code that will be very helpful tnx.

Comment: Seems like you have some issues with quotation marks here:  `accept-charset="utf-8 enctype="multipart/form-data""`

Comment: that i remove by mistake at the time of uploading here .. but that's not the issue though i checked that

Comment: Yeah, its still uploading i m getting the image locations as i wanted to but not the input text values. i checked removing that extra quote still the issue persist

Comment: You still have an extra set of double quotes up there in the OP.  Please fix before somebody wastes their time posting that as an answer.

Comment: Have you done any basic troubleshooting to determine where these values go missing?  Are they making it into the POST?

Comment: Why not use codeigniter form helper and use `<?php echo form_open_multipart('uploadproduct/upload');?>`

Comment: can you share a var_dump of post?

Comment: try to change in your ajax function 
`data: new FormData($("product-upload")),` Hope this helps.

Comment: @sparky yes i did that but its also not coming i m getting php error saying undefined index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **FormData() Method:**

As per our definition `.FormData()` submit a element data in a `Key/Value` form. The Form element must have a name attribute. One advantage of `FormData()` is now you can post a files on next page.

**Simple Syntax:**

```
var formData = new FormData(form);
```

**Highlight Points:**

1. This method does post files.
2. This method post complete form using Get & Post method including files.

   var formData = new FormData();

   formData.append('username', 'joe');
3. In addition you could add a key/value pair to this using `FormData.append`.

So your code broke because you need to pass value of input as key/pair format that you missed except for file.

Hope this will help you.

> **Please find solution describe below.**

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#add-product').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var formData = new FormData();

                //for product profile images
                var productProfile = $('#product-image').prop('files')[0];
                formData.append('file',productProfile);

                // for product detail image
                var imageCount = document.getElementById('product-screen').files.length;
                for (var i = 0; i< imageCount; i++) {
                    formData.append("files[]", document.getElementById('product-screen').files[i]);
                }
                var inputs = $('#product-upload input[type="text"],input[type="email"]');
                $.each(inputs, function(obj, v) {
                    var name = $(v).attr("name");
                    var value = $(v).val();
                    formData.append(name, value);
                });
                

                //AJAX Call
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://localhost/ci/index.php/uploadproduct/upload/', // point to server-side controller method
                    dataType: 'text', // what to expect back from the server
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: formData,
                    type: 'post',
                     beforeSend: function() {
                        // setting a timeout
                         $('#msg').html('Loading');
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#msg').html(response); // display success response from the server
                        $('input').attr('value').html();
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        $('#msg').html("no response"); // display error response from the server
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="custom-container">
        <div id="msg"></div>
            <form  id="product-upload" action="/index.php/uploadproduct/upload" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="product-name">Product name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_name" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="product-name">Product Code</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_code" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="product-name">Product Link</label>
                    <input type="text" name="product_link" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="product-image">Product image</label>
                    <input type="file" id="product-image" name="product_image" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="product-name">Product Screenshots</label>
                    <input type="file" id="product-screen" name="product_screen" class="form-control" multiple>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="add-product" type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add new product">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Let me know if it not works for you.

Comment: Also you can check same type of query with answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45206322/1441822

Comment: Wow!! tnx shyam that code u gave works like a charm.. 
that link one doesn't work though but its ok :))
i am very happy tyvm for the support Shyam :))

Comment: i would like to know why such behavior isn't formdata supposed to make an array of all input field by itself automatically rather then making a new array by looping ?

Comment: Please go through this link, it will take you in depth with using formData. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects

Comment: This would be a much better answer if you took the time explain why OP's code is broken.

Comment: @Sparky: Please check my updated answer, I tried to cover why his code broke in little description with example.